# Derivation of the Probability of Type II Error in Hypothesis Testing

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been trying to understand the formulas that have been derived for estimating the Type II error for the following two cases one-tailed test and two-tailed test. I have difficulty in understanding the proof for the one-tailed test and as a consequence, I am not able to understand the proof for the two-tailed test. I have read several articles on the internet, but the concept still remains cloudy. In particular, I don't understand why is it necessary to draw another curve (True distribution) and then use the critical values obtained from the test distribution to estimate the probability.

PS. I hope to develop an intuition for these things rather than cramming them and would be grateful if anyone could help me to do so.

Comment: Possibly an interesting question. It would help to know what kind of data (normal? Bernoulli?) you have in mind and what kind of test you are using. That would enable showing a relevant example upon which to start building intuition. Also say something about the level of the relevant course or about your background in statistical inference. As it stands, the question is too vague.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try to address all the questions. First, I am more interested in the error analysis of data distributed Normally. I am currently studying Further Math (IB), which I think is roughly equivalent to introductory statistics courses at college.